# IR_Black for OSX Lion colors dont display

Tags: shell, colors, terminal, themes

Hey so I installed IR_Black.terminal using the tutorial here: http://blog.toddwerth.com/entries/13

And it's super simple. Download file, run file. Done. However i've done this on 3 different mamcbook pros with the same result. nothing happens. The BG and the FG color changes but when I do a 
$ ls -la
It's not colorful like in the picture: http://d.pr/cehd
I want my folders to be one color and my files to be another like in tutorial screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following in your .bash_profile: export CLICOLOR=1